# Why does multiplesOf num max = [num*k | k <- [1..floor (max/num)]] throw an error?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a set of all the multiples of a number `num` under an upper limit `max`. I have written the following function in Haskell:

```
multiplesOf num max = [num*k | k <- [1..floor (max/num)]]
```

Why does this function throw the following error during run-time and how can it be fixed?

```
<interactive>:26:1: error:
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    ...plus 22 others
    ...plus 18 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

This error was thrown when, for example, entering `multiplesOf 3 1000`.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as an image.

Comment: This is not really an error that arises from the program. Haskell is simply unsure what type to pick in order to *print* the results. Furthermore you make it close to impossible to print this, since your function requires the output type to be both `Integral`, and `RealFrac` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in *defining* the function. The error is more when you want to *use* the function.

If we take a look at the type of the function you have constructed, we see:

```
multiplesOf :: (RealFrac t, Integral t) => t -> t -> [t]
```

So here the type of input and output values should both be `Integral`, and `RealFrac`. So that means that number should be `Integral`, but at the same time support real division. There are not much types that would fit these requirements.

This problem arises from the fact that you use `(/)` and `floor` here, which hints that `max` and `num` are `RealFrac`s, but the result of `floor` is an `Integral`, and then you mulitply numbers out of this range again with `num`.

You can however reduce the amount of type constraints, by making use of [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div). This is thus integer division, and the result is truncated towards negative infinity, so we can implement the function like:

```
multiplesOf :: Integral i => i -> i -> [i]
multiplesOf num max = [num*k | k <- [1..div max num]]
```

or we can even save us the trouble of making divisions, multiplications, etc. and work with a range expression that does the work for us:

```
multiplesOf :: (Num n, Enum n) => n -> n -> [n]
multiplesOf num max = [num, (num+num) .. max]
```

The latter is even less constraint, since `Integral i` implies `Real i` and `Enum i`.

Comment: Does `div` truncating the result toward negative infinity mean the same thing as the result of the division being rounded to the nearest integer that is less than or equal to the result?

Comment: @K.Claesson: yes, and in case of negative numbers `div (-3) 2` is `-2`.